# Magento 2 installation: requirements could not be resolved

Tags: composer-php, magento2

Following step 4 in [Get Magento of this guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#integrator-first-composer-ce), I ran into the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Followed by a list of missing extensions (such as `gd` and `dom`).

How can I install all of those extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer is **not** a package manager, it is a dependency manager, so it will not install native php packages. You need to install required packages according to your version of PHP and OS. Instructions for Centos are [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html) and that for Ubuntu is [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html)